# PnP provisioning Frame work import search configuration

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, pnp-provision

Through PNP provisioning frame work I am Provisioning some Site column, Lists, JS, CSS etc file to a newly created site. It work fine but when i tried to Import a Existing Search XML to the newly updated site i got error.**Schema can't be modified since the application is paused**

Through this search xml import i am Importing some Search Result Source & some Refining Columns and using the Source Id some where in Search Result Webparts.

Please help me how to over come this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait a moment and try to do this again, because it seems that this error is temporary.

[Link 1](https://nishantrana.me/2013/02/07/schema-cant-be-modified-since-the-application-is-paused-error-in-sharepoint-2013-online/)

[Link 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dfaf0073-68f0-4632-aeb8-0902a118bc86/schema-cant-be-modified-since-the-application-is-paused-in-sharepoint-2013-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Yes you are correct but main question is what is exact time I need to wait..as I am doing programmatically